# How to run every test only once?

Tags: testng

For instance I have the next set of test. Three groups. I want to run the next sequence of groups:

- SMOKE
- FEATURE_1
- FEATURE_2

And I do not want to run test twice, for instance, smokeAndFeature1 test.

Can I archive this goal using testNG only?

From my side I see several solutions:

1. Create test suite using java, but not xml
2. Use god object to store meta data about executed test cases and skip test in listener if test was executed before
3. Somehow use BeanShell scripts inside `<method-selector>` tag

   public class GroupsTest {

   ```
   private static final String SMOKE = "SMOKE";
   private static final String FEATURE_1 = "FEATURE_1";
   private static final String FEATURE_2 = "FEATURE_2";;

   @Test(groups = {SMOKE})
   public void smokeOnly(){
       System.out.println("smokeOnly");
   }

   @Test(groups = {FEATURE_1})
   public void feature1Only() {
       System.out.println("feature1Only");
   }

   @Test(groups = {FEATURE_2})
   public void feature2Only() {
       System.out.println("feature2Only");
   }

   @Test(groups = {FEATURE_1, SMOKE})
   public void smokeAndFeature1() {
       System.out.println("smokeAndFeature1");
   }

   @Test(groups = {FEATURE_2, SMOKE})
   public void smokeAndFeature2() {
       System.out.println("smokeAndFeature2");
   }

   @Test(groups = {FEATURE_2, FEATURE_1})
   public void feature1AndFeature2() {
       System.out.println("feature1AndFeature2");
   }

   @Test(groups = {SMOKE, FEATURE_2, FEATURE_1})
   public void smokeFeature1AndFeature2() {
       System.out.println("smokeFeature1AndFeature2");
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: You cannot do this, if you tie your `@Test` method to two or more groups and include them in your execution plan. If a `@Test` method is part of two or more groups and you are selecting all those groups, then TestNG will execute those methods that many number of times.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan, Thanks, I answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out what I wanted to do. I rid of idea to use groups. it needed to run only one test ones.

For instance, if I have 4 devices to run first one device will start only 1st, 5th, 9th etc test. Second device 2nd, 6th, 10th etc.

I used method selector mechanism that is provided by testng.

My method selector implementation:

```
import org.testng.IMethodSelector;
import org.testng.IMethodSelectorContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;

import java.util.List;

public class ParallelExecutionMethodSelector implements IMethodSelector {
    private int counter = 1;
    private int part    = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean includeMethod(IMethodSelectorContext context, ITestNGMethod method, boolean isTestMethod) {

        if (isTestMethod) {
            final int testIndex   = 1 + method.getXmlTest().getIndex();
            final int partVal     = part;
            final int testNumber  = method.getXmlTest().getSuite().getTests().size();

            // split a list of test in chunks
            if (counter / partVal == testNumber ) {
                part++;
            }

            // pick up only a test with the value id as current test index
            boolean include = (counter - testNumber * (partVal - 1) == testIndex);

            // To disable the next method selector class
            context.setStopped(true);

            counter++;

            return include;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTestMethods(List<ITestNGMethod> testMethods) {
    }
}
```

I use it with the next testng xml configuration

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Debug" parallel="tests" thread-count="4">
    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <selector-class name="com.example.ParallelExecutionMethodSelector" />
        </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>

    <test name="Debug Thread-1" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="22456BDE5D448B047D8A4"/>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.mobile.tests.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>

    <test name="Debug Thread-2" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="2F212D84C28C8AED24F0E"/>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.mobile.tests.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>

    <test name="Debug Thread-3" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="A91730017660D2215CA6A"/>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.mobile.tests.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>

    <test name="Debug Thread-4" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="3AFEC04596F29DA3A7948"/>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.mobile.tests.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```